# Error reading delta file, stateful spark structured streaming job with kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I m reading data through kafka with spark windowing operation and union the kafka and hive data , make single dataframe. I am trying to find latest data with timestamp through spark window function and row_number then save dataframe in hive table.

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession =
SparkSession.builder().appName(SPARK_APP_NAME)

.config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", SPARK_HIVE_WAREHOUSE_DIR_SUSPICIOUS_USER)
// .config("spark.default.parallelism",70)
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
.config("hive.support.concurrency", true)
.config("spark.sql.orc.impl","native")
.config("spark.speculation","false")

query = kakfa_SuspciousUser
.selectExpr(
"nullif(TimeStamp, \"\") as TimeStamp",
"nullif(UserName, \"\") as UserName"
)
.groupBy(window(col("TimeStamp"), "30 minute"), col("UserName"))
.agg(functions.count("UserName").alias("user_UserCount"))
.select("UserName","window.end", "user_UserCount")
.filter(col("user_UserCount").gt(4))
.writeStream
.foreachBatch(function = (batchDF: Dataset[Row], batchId: Long) =>
{ 
println("drop table if exists CompromiseUserID_transaction") 

val hive_target_Table = hiveCache.sparkSession.table("User_temp_table") 
println("before hive") /* WRITE FINAL DATASET IN SuspiciousIP HIVE TABLE */ 
 hive_target_Table
.write.mode(SaveMode.Append)  
.format("hive")
.saveAsTable("parichaynew.CompromiseUserIDTable")})
.outputMode("update").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
.option("checkpointLocation",CHECK_POINT)
.start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Please update your post with the error.

Comment: FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, hcube1-1n03.eng.hortonworks.com, executor 1): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file /checkpointDir/state/0/0/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=0), dir = /checkpointDir/state/0/0]: /checkpointDir/state/0/0/1.delta does not exist atorg.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.